# How to define a branch name in Github workflow form the input while addressing the 'uses' section?

Tags: kubernetes, github, github-actions, cicd

For a job in my Github workflow, I need to define the branch that is used by the `uses` component.

As of now, it is hardcoded to `main` and I have to manually change it to the branch I desire, when changing the referred file.

I want to template-ize it leveraging the user input feature.

Initially, it was:

```
uses: "main_folder/<repo name>/.github/workflows/deploy.yaml@main"
```

Now, I aim to define it as:

```
uses: "main_folder/repo_name/.github/workflows/deploy.yaml@${{ branch_name }}"
```

I get the error:

```
invalid value workflow reference: version cannot have whitespace: ${{ branch_name }}
```

I also tried to enclose the whole *value* in double quotes but then the workflow failed without any error.

For reference, this is my workflow:

```
name: <cluster_name> Release

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      dry_run:
        type: boolean
        required: true
        default: true
      database_version:
        type: string
        required: true
      branch_name:
        type: string
        required: true
        default: main

jobs:
  deploy_gcp:
    name: Deploy to <test cluster>
    if: ${{ contains('["<user 1>", "<user 2>",]', github.actor) }}
    needs:
      - helm
      - docker
    uses: "<main folder>/<repo name>/.github/workflows/deploy.yaml@${{ branch_name }}"
    with:
      cloud: gcp
      cluster_name: <>
      <product>_region: <>
      region: <>
      dry_run: false
      gcp_service_account: <>
      gcp_project: <>
      slack_channel: <>
      database_version: <>
    secrets:
      <some secrets>
```

Comment: See https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/25246#discussioncomment-3247073.

Comment: Apart from that the dynamic configuration of `uses` is not supported at the moment, the valid reference to `branch_name` would be `inputs.branch_name`.